# Combining Aggregated Dependent Data with Granular Independent Data

Tags: dataset

As data science newbie, I thought I was on the right tract until something doesn't seem right after plotting. A simplified structure of my dataset is as follows:

- FIPS (Census Tract ID)
- Drug-related death rate per 100K **by county** (dependent variable)
- Demographic A count by Census Tract
- Demographic B count by Census Tract
- ...

In other words, as drug-related death data is only available by county, my data consists of an aggregated dependent variable and many other granular independent variables. My questions are:

1. Is there a better option to prepare my data? One option I can think of is to aggregate (or average) Census Tract data to county level so there is an one-to-one, instead of one-to-many relationship. However, I feel that this approach may lose the benefit of identifying key population metrics at individual Census Tract level.
2. Should I transform/normalize the demographic data from counts to per 100K like my dependent variable?

Thanks in advance for sharing your wisdom!